Airport transit visa in Greece required?
Egyptian passport holder, with settled status in UK, traveling UK-Cairo, with a 2-hour layover in Athens.
Considering the flight is from a non-Schengen state to a non-Schengen state, is a transit visa for Athens required?

Are the two flights on the same ticket? What is the airline?

No, in this specific combination, if both flights are on the same ticket, you don't need one:

Egypt is not on the list of countries whose citizens always need an airport transit visa for any Schengen country
While Egyptian citizens need an ATV for transit via airports in Czechia, Poland and Romania, they don't need one for other Schengen countries, including Greece

If the flights are on separate tickets (as is often the case with many low-cost carriers), also known as a self-transfer, then a full Schengen visa will be required (but in addition 2 hours would probably make it a very risky connection, bordering on impossible with checked bags).

UK settled status should help in any case, no?

@Relaxed UK settled status usually applies to EU citizens, which of course do not need a visa to transit or visit Greece. I suppose OP got it as a family member, but as far as I know, no UK residence status or visa gives any right in Schengen, even for ATVs (contrary  to status in the US, Canada, and a few others).
